# Mysql CASE returning NULL Multiple times

Tags: mysql

I am making a case to get a user's friends . There is a system in which is_confirmed = 1 means friends an is_confirmed = 0 means still pending but request is sent . I need to get all friends which are is_confirmed = 1 . The query is returning NULL as i wanted if there is no friends or if the case is 0 and there are pending request but . Its returning multiple NULLS .

```
SELECT CASE WHEN friend_user_id =  '935'
                AND is_confirmed =  '1'
            THEN initiator_user_id
            WHEN initiator_user_id =  '935'
                AND is_confirmed =  '1'
            THEN friend_user_id
            ELSE NULL 
    END AS friend_id
FROM wp_bp_friends
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Also is using CASE the best way out here ?

SQL FIDDLE [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/66c0b/1)

Comment: Are the 1s actually text in need of tick marks or can you remove them?

Comment: I think sample data, desired results, and actual results would really help convey your question.  SQL Fiddle is a very useful resource.

Comment: Ofcourse . Ill make a sqlfiddle :)

Comment: 1 or 0 is just numbers i use as 1 for confirmed and 0 for pending for my understanding

Comment: I'm curious as to what removing the ' would do.

Comment: Why shouldn't it return multiple `NULL`s? Since you have no `WHERE` clause, it returns a row of results for each row in the table. Since most of the rows don't match either `WHEN` condition, there will bt lots of nulls.

Comment: added sqlfiddle . But already got a negative vote :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think CASE is not the best way to do that. An other way can be :

```
(
    /* 1) */
    SELECT wp_bp_friends.initiator_user_id AS FriendId
        FROM wp_bp_friends
        WHERE
            wp_bp_friends.friend_user_id = 935
            AND wp_bp_friends.is_confirmed = '1'
)
UNION
(
    /* 2) */
    SELECT wp_bp_friends.friend_user_id AS FriendId
        FROM wp_bp_friends 
        WHERE
            wp_bp_friends.initiator_user_id = 935
            AND wp_bp_friends.is_confirmed = '1'
)
```

It will concatenate the Id's of
**1)** the confirmed friends of 935 who were the initiators
**2)** the confirmed friends of 935 for which the user 935 was the initiator

Answer (score 0):

Use two queries:

- ```
  SELECT friend_user_id FROM wp_bp_friends
  WHERE initiator_user_id='935' AND is_confirmed='1'
  ```
- ```
  SELECT initiator_user_id FROM wp_bp_friends
  WHERE friend_user_id='935' AND is_confirmed='1'
  ```

Or combine them into one:

```
(
    SELECT friend_user_id FROM wp_bp_friends
    WHERE initiator_user_id='935' AND is_confirmed='1'
) UNION ALL (
    SELECT initiator_user_id FROM wp_bp_friends
    WHERE friend_user_id='935' AND is_confirmed='1'
)
```